# I/O Xen Server on disk filesystem ext4

Tags: centos, xen, io

I have a Xen Server 6.0 and one disk (2TB) report I/O error my vm is Centos 6.2 (filesystem ext4)

```
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084224
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084312
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084400
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084488
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084576
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084664
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084752
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084840
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896084928
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085016
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085104
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085192
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085280
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085368
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085456
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085544
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085632
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085720
end_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 896085808
```

Smart check:

```
   smartctl version 5.38 [i686-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   114   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       65412104
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       23
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   072   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       18633333
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       5873
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       26
183 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   063   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Lifetime Min/Max 30/35)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 22 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   026   003   000    Old_age   Always       -       65412104
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       64587718203122
241 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3045564792
242 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       78354915

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Self-test routine in progress 10%      5873
```

its bug of xen?

Comment: could be a faulty cable or the disk is about to fail, S.M.A.R.T does not always predict disk failures.

Comment: badblocks -v /dev/xvdc no report problems, maybe a faulty cable ?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for real hardware errors in dom0.

Comment: have a lot of end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081232
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081320
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081408
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081496
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081584
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081672
end_request: I/O error, dev tdd, sector 896081760

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your backups are good. That kind of error typically means you have a dying drive.

It's possible that there's a cable or controller issue, but usually I've found this means the drive is getting ready to nail you with a full blown no-more-boot situation, preceded by a sudden system freeze. Especially if the system was working fine before this for a decent period of time.

At best, reseat the cables. At worst, your backups are about to be tested.

Comment: thanks, the system run was working very fine about 1 year, the disk have 1 year of use too and the error present about 1 week until short electric affect my office.

Comment: @mbarrera so it might be your controller as well.